# what are the fppf covers of an algebraically closed field

Tags: algebraic-geometry, grothendieck-topologies

I'm trying to get a feel for Grothendieck topologies by considering some really simple examples (and this relates to a question in Kleiman's chapter on the Picard Scheme in FGA explained).

I know that the etale covers of $\text{Spec}(k)$ are precisely the spectra of finite separable field extensions of $k$ (or perhaps finite disjoint unions of such spectra). Thus if $k$ is algebraically closed, there are no non-trivial etale covers.

So, moving to the finer fppf topology, I'd like to know what the fppf covers of $\text{Spec}(k)$ for $k$ an algebraically closed field look like. This is how far I've got:

If $T\xrightarrow{f} \text{Spec}(k)$ is fppf, then for any open affine $U = \text{Spec}(A)\subset T$, $A$ must be a finitely presented $k$-algebra. It will automatically be flat over $k$, since $k$ is a field.

I can't see any other restriction on $T$, so it apears as if the fppf covers of $\text{Spec}(k)$ should be all $k$-schemes of finite type. But this seems like way too many covers, especially considering how there weren't any etale covers. So have I done this right or am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know anything about this, but Wikipedia has an additional condition of "quasi-finiteness" which I think here implies that $A$ must be finite-dimensional.

Comment: That makes sense, but the definition used in Nlab http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/fppf+site and also in the stacks project don't require quasi-finiteness

Comment: As far as I can tell, any non-empty scheme of finite type over $k$ will be an fppf cover. Similarly, any non-empty quasicompact scheme over $k$ will be an fpqc cover.

Comment: Yup, that seems to be the consensus among people I've asked to, thanks!